# Does iOS NFC Background Reading support NDEF Contact Card records?

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc, core-nfc

I'm just getting into NFC Tags for iOS and I want to program a contact record into an NFC tag so that it can be read by an iPhone that supports Background Tag Reading. It seems like Background Tag Reading in iOS only supports universal links and certain URI/URL messages. This is the link I read for reference:

[Background Tag Reading Support Info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading)

I know that Android supports the NDEF VCard Record Type, where one can then program a tag with a contact's info, and then scan and add that contact. I noticed that when I used the same tag with Apple, nothing showed up, so that's why I am assuming Apple doesn't support this NDEF Record type.

First off, am I correct in this information so far? Apple does not support NDEF VCard Records?

If that's true, is there any way to program a contact in or is the closest I'm going to get to a contact through the use of the `tel:+14085551212` url, as stated by the link above?

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes only URIs are identified by iOS. For v-Card you must use a third party app. The app I made for example can handle v-Cards. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nfc-for-iphone/id1249686798

Apple might open this in the future but who knows...

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using URL NDEF record itself. Just host a vcard on a URL and use that for URL NDEF record. Scanning the tag will trigger browser, and opening it will open the contact application with the details in the vcard loaded.

Note the URL should have VCARD content, and content type header should be text/x-vcard. You can create one using service like [www.vcard.link](https://www.vcard.link)